# Python: print even numbers including 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a program that outputs all the numbers from 0 to 10, I must print only the even numbers. I'm using this code:

```
x = 0
while x <= 10:
    x += 1
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(x)
```

The output shows numbers from 2 to 10, excluding 0, which I need to include.
How can I print even numbers from 0 to 10?

Thanks!

** Note: I'm a beginner, so any explanation is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, the problem is that you're incrementing `x` before you check if it's even, so you increment from `0` to `1` before printing.

But there's no need for the test, you can just loop over the even numbers:

```
for x in range(0, 11, 2):
    print(x)
```

The third argument to `range()` is the steps, and stepping by 2 just returns even numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a beginner and your explanation helps a lot

Answer (score 3):

```
x = 0
while x <= 10:
     if x % 2 == 0:
          print(x)
     x += 1 # increment x AFTER the if statement, otherwise you never check if 0%2 == 0
```

You could also use a for-loop to simplify things further:

```
for x in range(11):
     if x%2 == 0:
          print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Increment `x` after the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm....can you ask quiz questions on here? anyhow, I think the small edit to the order of operations in your loop should do it?

```
x = 0
while x <= 10:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

Comment: You can ask any question on here as long as it follows the [ask] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

This can be esaily done with the `for` loop:

```
for i in range(11):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
```

and that's all it takes, 3 lines :)

Comment: Watch out, this will not run when x=10 !

Answer (score 0):

Its fine!

```
x = 0
while x <= 10:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different slant on a on-liner ... just for fun.

```
print(*(i for i in range(0, 11, 2)))

>>> 0 2 4 6 8 10
```